# Angular 5 material data grid auto height

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I need to set height of data grid automatically depending og children height. I have 2 rows and 2 columns, but when I set height of card, and for example enter looooong text in "p" child, i just get hidden overflow.

Ideally it would be to have row height depending on heigher of 2 children.
Current html:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="200px" gutterSize="30px">
                    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
                        <div fxFlex="100%" fxLayout="row">
                            <div fxFlex="20%" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <img [src]="src" [matTooltipPosition]="'above'"/>
                            </div>
                            <div  fxFlex="80%" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center none">
                                <div>
                                    <div>MY LABEL</div>
                                    <p>loong description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <a>link</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </mat-grid-tile>
etc..
```

Any ideas?
Thx...